# How to Append to URL when onchange="document.my-form.sumbit"

Tags: php, javascript, forms

How to I add a value of (#vs) to the end of the existing URL when someone selects a form option shown below?

```
<form name="vs_form" action="" method="post">
<select name="vs_team" onchange="document.vs_form.submit();">
<option value="-1"> - <?php _e('team'); ?> - </option>
<?php foreach(get_player_played_teams($player) as $t): ?>
<option value="<?php print $t['team_id'] ?>" <?php print ($vs_team == $t['team_id']) ?       'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php print $t['team_name'] ?></option>
</select>
</form>
```

Right now, when they select an option from the form, the script processes, however I want to add to the URL so I can move the user to the area of the page where the results are shown.

**Existing URL:**

```
http://somedomain/Mike-11084/
```

**What User needs onchange:**

```
http://somedomain/Mike-11084/#vs
```

Please provide code example. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript/[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) build the url manually. Might look kinda like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="vs_team"]').change(function() {
        var vs_team = $(this).val();
        window.location('http://somedomain/' + vs_team + '/#vs');
    });
});
```

You'll also need to get rid of this line in your code:

```
onchange="document.vs_form.submit();"
```

And of course, you'll need to include jQuery.